# Can't restart OpenShift application

Tags: openshift-online-2

```
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/diy
```

OpenShift application won't let me restart via the console or the web interface!

```
[xxxxx.rhcloud.com 52692eb65973ca78800000c0]\> ctl_app stop
Stopping gear...
Stopping DIY cartridge
+ cd /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data//tomcat
+ bin/shutdown.sh
Aug 11, 2014 9:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:453)
```

web interface...

```
Stopping DIY cartridge
Starting DIY cartridge

+ cd /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data//tomcat
+ bin/shutdown.sh
Aug 11, 2014 9:37:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:453)
+ export 'CATALINA_OPTS= -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data//prefs'
+ CATALINA_OPTS=' -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data//prefs'
+ cd /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data//tomcat
+ sed -ig s/OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP/127.10.44.129/g conf/server.xml
+ bin/startup.sh
touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data/tomcat/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
/var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 389: /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/app-root/data/tomcat/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/52692eb65973ca78800000c0/diy
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some more information around your app?

Comment: Connection refused usually means that its trying to listen on the wrong ports have you configured your application to use the right OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP and OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT environment variables? Also I noticed that you're getting does not exist errors. Have you been able to confirm that those directories exist on your gear?